# How do use a class defined/declared several namespace level up in a different file

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, nested

Lets say I have different files

preference.h

```
namespace level1 {

    namespace level2 {

        class Common {};  

    }
}
```

preference_type1.h

```
#include "preference.h"

    namespace level1 {
       namespace level2{
           namespace level2typeA {
               class typeA {
                  private:
                     level1::level2::Common CommonForTypeA();
               }
           }
      }
    }
```

preference_type1.h

```
include "preference.h"    

namespace level1 {
    namespace level2{
        namespace level2typeB {
             class typeB {
               private:
               level1::level2::Common CommonForTypeB();
             }
         }
      }
    }
```

The above will result in an error that Common : is not a member of 'level1::level2'. What is the explanation why this is wrong and what is the correct implementation for this type of situation?

Comment: You need to include `preference.h` and put a missing `;` after class definitions.

Comment: Have you included preference.h in preference_type1.h?

Comment: Yes I have put preference.h in them sorry forgot it in this example

Comment: Did not try, maybe `::level1::level2::Common` solves your problem?

Comment: I tried your suggestion Aconcagua. adding an accessor in front of level1 still has the same error. I am not sure if this has something to do with forward declaration and the #pragma once directive

Comment: [mcve], please. Not this pseudocode.

Comment: we need a [mcve] to help you, the code above apart from missing semi colons on classes compiles correctly